# LDAP search for CNs within a OU

Tags: php, ldap

I am trying to find all members of a specific OU from a Lotus Notes database.
the hierarchy is `CN/OU/O`. For example there are users called `Mike Smith/NY/DIR`.

When I search for `(cn=Mike*)` on a base `DN` of `O=DIR`, I get all users that are called "Mike...".

I have tried [the process here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19302165/ldap-filter-find-all-users-of-specific-ou) to get all users, but I get an "No such object" back. What I did was

```
$list = ldap_search($ldap_conn, "OU=NY,O=DIR", "(objectclass=person)", array("sn"));
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

your filter must be like: (&(objectclass=person)(uid=*)(ou:dn:=NY))
or I dont get it

Comment: I am getting a protocol error, are you sure about the "ou:dn:= ... "?

Comment: give me a dn of a random account

Comment: "CN=Mike Smith,OU=NY,O=DIR"

Comment: with the filter I gave you, your ldap_search returns you all the objectclass=person with OU=NY
btw, ou:dn:NY means you need all person with ou=NY in the dn

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the baseDN for the search to the OU containing the users you are interested in. OU=NY and then the search filter (cn=Mike Smith)

I would doubt that Notes supports Extensible Match Filters.