# python ldap search returns error when ou is filtered

Tags: python, ldap, ou

I have a python script to search in an LDAP server. I used to search filtering the DC in my base DN. Now, I want to expand my filter to OU too. But when I use OU in my base DN, I get following error:

```
/usr/bin/python3.6 /home/zeinab/PycharmProjects/ldap-test/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zeinab/PycharmProjects/ldap-test/main.py", line 29, in <module>
    search_scope=SUBTREE)
  File "/home/zeinab/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ldap3/core/connection.py", line 853, in search
    response = self.post_send_search(self.send('searchRequest', request, controls))
  File "/home/zeinab/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ldap3/strategy/sync.py", line 178, in post_send_search
    responses, result = self.get_response(message_id)
  File "/home/zeinab/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ldap3/strategy/base.py", line 403, in get_response
    raise LDAPOperationResult(result=result['result'], description=result['description'], dn=result['dn'], message=result['message'], response_type=result['type'])
ldap3.core.exceptions.LDAPOperationsErrorResult: LDAPOperationsErrorResult - 1 - operationsError - None - 000020D6: SvcErr: DSID-03100837, problem 5012 (DIR_ERROR), data 0
  - searchResDone - None
```

This is my script:

```
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, SIMPLE, ALL, SUBTREE

server = Server(host=host, port=port, get_info=ALL, connect_timeout=10, use_ssl=True)
connection = Connection(
    server=server,
    user=username,
    password=password,
    raise_exceptions=True,
    authentication=SIMPLE,
)

connection.open()
connection.bind()

base_dn = "dc=dc1,dc=local,ou=ou0,ou=ou1"
search_filter = "(&(objectClass=person)(mail=john*))"
search_attribute = ['mail']

connection.search(search_base=base_dn,
                  search_filter=search_filter,
                  attributes=search_attribute,
                  search_scope=SUBTREE)
resp = connection.response
print(len(resp))
print(resp)
connection.unbind()
```

**EDIT 1:**
I have also tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28346124/1626977):

```
base_dn = "dc=dc1,dc=local,ou=ou0,ou=ou1"
search_filter = "(&(objectClass=person)(mail=john*)(ou:dn:=ou1))"
```

But I got the exact same error.

**EDIT 2:**
I tried [previous solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28346124/1626977) this way:

```
base_dn = "dc=dc1,dc=local"
search_filter = "(&(objectClass=person)(mail=john*)(ou:dn:=ou1))"
```

And also this way:

```
base_dn = "dc=dc1,dc=local"
search_filter = "(&(objectClass=person)(mail=john*)(ou:=ou1))"
```

These two didn't raise any error, but returned no result; even though I have results matching the filter.

Comment: What happens if you match the `ou` value the same way you're matching the `objectClass` and `mail` attributes? `(&(objectClass=person)(mail=john*)(ou=ou1))`

Comment: What LDAP service are you using?
Microsoft Active Directory does not support ou:dn:=ou1

Also, are you sure the OU values are populated on (objectClass=person)?

Comment: nothing returns @larsks

Comment: I am using Microsoft Active Directory. And yes, I am sure that the ou is filled with the values I'm filtering @jwilleke

Answer (score 1):

> This is my script:
>
> ```py
> base_dn = "dc=dc1,dc=local,ou=ou0,ou=ou1"
> ```

Your DN is backwards. LDAP-format DNs are hierarchical **from right to left** – the child of `dc=dc,dc=local` would actually be `ou=ou0,dc=dc1,dc=local`. In other words, the directory structure would look like this – imagine it like a filesystem structure but with the paths going right-to-left:

```
DC=example,DC=com
 └─OU=Users,DC=example,DC=com
    └─OU=Staff,OU=Users,DC=example,DC=com
       └─CN=Fred Foobar,OU=Staff,OU=Users,DC=example,DC=com
```

Additionally, the "base DN" can only match a specific entry. If you have OU1 that is *inside* OU0, then a base DN of `OU=ou1,OU=ou0,DC=...` would be correct. But if you want to match OU1 *or* OU0, that cannot be done with a single search operation – you need to combine two searches, each under its own base.

> EDIT 1: I have also tried this solution:
>
> ```py
> base_dn = "dc=dc1,dc=local,ou=ou0,ou=ou1"
> search_filter = "(&(objectClass=person)(mail=john*)(ou:dn:=ou1))"
> ```

The `:dn:` modifier is, unfortunately, only supported by OpenLDAP (and maybe 389ds/FreeIPA). It is not supported by Active Directory; AD DCs treat the filter as if it were just `(ou=ou1)`, which will never match the child entries.